# For loop to take the value of the whole array each time

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

Suppose I have 3 arrays, A, B and C

I want to do the following:

```
A=("1" "2")
B=("3" "4")
C=("5" "6")

for i in $A $B $C; do
   echo ${i[0]} ${i[1]}
   #process data etc
done
```

So, basically `i` takes the value of the whole array each time and I am able to access the specific data stored in each array.

On the 1st loop, `i` should take the value of the 1st array, `A`, on the 2nd loop the value of array `B` etc.

The above code just iterates with `i` taking the value of the first element of each array, which clearly isn't what I want to achieve.

So the code only outputs 1, 3 and 5.

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: @Leo `bash`, like it says in the tags.

Comment: oh, ok, sorry, my bad

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want. `bash` doesn't have any way to assign a whole array to a variable.

Comment: @Barmar, eh? `new_array=( "${old_array[@]}" )` is precisely that. What's tricky is doing it indirectly; that needs either namevars (a 4.3 feature), or `eval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in a fully safe and supportable way, but only in bash 4.3 (which adds `namevar` support), a feature ported over from ksh:

```
for array_name in A B C; do
  declare -n current_array=$array_name
  echo "${current_array[0]}" "${current_array[1]}"
done
```

That said, there's hackery available elsewhere. For instance, you can use `eval` (allowing a malicious variable name to execute arbitrary code, but otherwise safe):

```
for array_name in A B C; do
  eval 'current_array=( "${'"$array_name"'[@]}"'
  echo "${current_array[0]}" "${current_array[1]}"
done
```

Comment: I have bash 4.3.11 and I get invalid option errors: http://i.imgur.com/KWZOZaA.png (even if I remove the `C` that I erroneously put there)

Comment: @hakermania, ahh -- it's `declare -n`. Sorry 'bout that; was working from memory, as I don't have bash 4.3 on the system I'm currently on.

Answer (score 1):

If the elements of the arrays don't contain spaces or wildcard characters, as in your question, you can do:

```
for i in "${A[*]}" "${B[*]}" "${C[*]}"
do
    iarray=($i)
    echo ${iarray[0]} ${iarray[1]}
    # process data etc
done
```

`"${A[*]}"` expands to a single string containing all the elements of `${A[*]}`. Then `iarray=($i)` splits this on whitespace, turning the string back into an array.

Comment: Thanks this works in some cases but Duffy's answer is more general.